# Can you use semicolons to separate clauses that are not part of a serial list?

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

I don't understand how the two semicolons are being used in the following sentence from Ralph Ellison's [*Invisible Man*](https://books.google.com/books?id=foSLDQAAQBAJ&pg=PA35&dq=red+clay+roads,+and+beyond+a+certain+river&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQhvL-gYHRAhUN7mMKHWD2B60Q6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=red%20clay%20roads%2C%20and%20beyond%20a%20certain%20river&f=false):

> And I stand as for an answer and see in my mind's eye the cabins surrounded by empty fields beyond red clay roads, and beyond a certain river, sluggish and covered with algae more yellow than green in its stagnant stillness**;** past more empty fields to the sun-shrunk shacks at the railroad crossing where the disabled veterans visited the whores, hobbling down the tracks on crutches and canes**;** sometimes pushing the legless, thigh-less one in a wheelchair.

The semicolons aren't separating independent clauses and they aren't separating different elements of a list. Are they being used as a sort of "super comma" to string together different dependent clauses?

Comment: Interesting question. The semicolons here seem to be operating at different levels. The first seems to further a primary-level parallel construction: "and see in my mind's eye the cabins ... and beyond a certain river ... [and] past [that] more empty fields ..." But the second one seems to extend a subordinate extension of the sentence into a second parallel structure: "disabled veterans hobbling down the tracks ... [and] sometimes pushing the legless, thighless one ..." To me, the effect is dreamlike—a memory that keeps unexpectedly discovering new elements as it roves the remembered scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Punctuation is a stylistic aid to guide the reader to the correct parse of linear text. In the hands of a master, it can also guide a reader to the vision that the author intends to convey. Let's start out by listing what Ellison's narrator sees:

- cabins
- empty fields
- red clay roads
- a river
- yellow algae
- more empty fields
- shacks
- a railroad crossing
- disabled veterans
- tracks
- a legless man in a wheelchair

In the hands of an untalented author, this list of viewed objects could simply be spilled out, each separated from the next by a comma. But that's not what Ellison does. First he gathers three initial sights:

1. cabins
2. beyond the river to the shacks
3. past more empty fields

(Notice that 1 is a direct object, while 2 and 3 are prepositional phrases, which give a sweep to the narrator's vision.) Secondly, he places the other images mostly as **adjuncts** or parts of adjuncts (i.e., modifiers) to the three:

1. cabins **surrounded by empty fields**
2. beyond the river, sluggish ... **covered by algae**
3. past more empty fields **to the ... shacks at the railroad crossing where the ... veterans visited ..., hobbling down the tracks**

This is still a list, but the second has an internal comma (between *river* and *sluggish*), so it would be misleading for a comma to separate 1. *beyond the river,* and 2. *past more empty fields*: a reader might expect another phrase or clause modifying *river*. So a semicolon stands in stead to separate the second sight from the third.

Now we come to the last element, the gerund clause

> sometimes pushing the legless, thigh-less one in a wheelchair.

Grammatically, this is a nominative absolute, a participial clause loosely connected syntactically to its associated clause

> veterans visited the whores

describing both the subject (the veterans) and the predicate (their visiting) by giving the manner of their action. Ordinarily a comma separates an absolute from its associated clause, but Ellison further loosens the attachment with a semicolon, stylistically making it part of the preceding list and suggesting that it's the final, fourth sight in the narrator's vista.